# Why does Blender add the stereoscopic suffix after the frame number instead of before?

Tags: rendering, stereoscopy

I would like to have the stereoscopic suffix after the frame number. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 2):

Because it’s a suffix? That’s where a suffix goes or it wouldn’t be a suffix.  Are you saying you want a prefix instead?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this if it's possible? I am in a similar situation using 8 multi-render cameras, outputting thousands of images for a project, currently trying to streamline my workflow, I did research on this subject and didn't comed with a solution for a long time now, been using third party tools for renaming. My desire was to set the filenames as animation_name + camera_name + animation_frame + format.

Comment: YES prefix instead, it doesn't make sense to have sequence ending with Framenumber_L. Animation is animation and it should have frame number on the end. SO naming should look like Name_L_number.ext